# Why doesn't my Node.js server reply with data?

Tags: macos, node.js

I'm doing the tutorial [here](http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html). I got everything working up until this point:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Http'); 
});

server.listen(8080);
```

When I run the above using `node hello_http.js` it doesn't exit as expected but then when I view `localhost:8080` in the browser there's nothing and when I `curl` it I get this:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

How should I look for the problem? One thing I should add is that I was playing around with Cherrypy a couple weeks ago and when I visit localhost in my browser I see the Cherrypy favicon. Is Cherrypy interfering with this in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the port from 8080 to 3000. 8080 is common port so you are most likely correct that an other server is using it.

Comment: I used 8000 and it works. But how can I see what's using 8080? or stop everything that is using 8080?

Comment: sudo netstat -lpn | grep 8080